# Ruby code refactoring

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I have n-times similar statements

```
    if trigger_data.tt_closed
      unless trouble_ticket.changes.key?(:status)
        @run = 0
        break
      end
      unless trouble_ticket.changes[:status][1] == "Closed"
        @run = 0
        break
      end
    end

    if trigger_data.tt_assignee
      unless trouble_ticket.changes.key?(:assigned_to)
        @run = 0
        break
      end
      unless trouble_ticket.changes[:assigned_to][1] == trigger_data.tt_assignee
        @run
        break
      end
    end
```

How to refactoring that code? Maybe dynamic statement build with pass some hash to input. I'm newbie in metaprogramming. Give me advise please

Comment: Please, direct similar questions to http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Voting to migrate this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it shortens code a lot.

Also, I removed those key?() methods, because if key doesn't exist, it just passes nil which in Ruby means the same as false for if statement.

I left it with 2 if statements for the sake of clarity. :)

```
changes = trouble_ticker.changes
if trigger_data.tt_closed && changes[:status][1] != "Closed"
  @run = 0
  break
end

if t = trigger_data.tt_assignee && changes[:assigned_to][1] != t)
  @run = 0
  break
end
```